# Gradle dependencies not imported into library project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Hey I've been trying for hours to import an Android library ([BetterPickers latest commit](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers)) into my project using Gradle

After importing and setting it as module, I get compilation errors. It seems like something is wrong with dependencies in my `build.gradle` .

[build.gradle of library project](http://pastebin.com/HRZnR9JB)
[build.gradle of main project](http://pastebin.com/3ey3BRCc)

As you can see, Android Studio suggests an autofix but it's not helpful.
[image: error]

When I try to run the project/Gradle build, I get compilation errors since the library project is dependent on `nineolddroids lib`. When I try to add `nineolddroids` to the dependencies I get a different error:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sub:bp:_DebugCompile'.
>
> Could not find com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0.)

I guess both of them are derived from the same thing.
How can I fix this?

## A few remarks

- Using latest Android Studio (0.2.5)
- Android Support Repository is installed
- In the main project, the support lib is imported just fine and I get no compilation errors when using classes from support lib
- Tried many ways to import the library project, including answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Comment: The two links for the gradle build files are the same.

Comment: Is the "library project" `:sub:bp`? If not, can you post the .gradle file for that? Thought, it seems you are referencing the NineOldAndroids library but it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: yes its the library project , and i already posted it its the first link above (build.gradle of library project), and the error i posted of nineolddroids is the log of `gradlew --refresh -dependencies`

Comment: 'but when i try to add nineolddroids to dependencies i get different error' - Did you add it to one of the gradle files? I can't find it...

Comment: @Bas yes if i add `compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'` to dependencies of library project gradle file i get the same error i mentioned

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?